# Model Class not showing when creating controller using Web API 2 Controller with actions using Entity Framework Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a WebAPI 2 application using Entity Framework 6. I have already created the model, using Entity Framework Database First Approach and I want to add a controller to my solution using Web API Controller with actions using Entity Framework. The problem I am having is that I don't know which model class to use. It is different from when using Entity Framework where I know which model class to use exactly.

[image]

My model classes.

[image]

Can someone please help/advise ?

Thanks

Comment: If you've created the model it is a pretty simple matter to use it an API Controller with Entity Framework. Looks like you are trying to scaffold and it may not be seeing your model for a variety of reasons. Maybe start by manually creating the controller, instantiating the context and doing a simple data fetch. Build up from there...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to build your project first after creating the entity model to be able to see the entity in the models list

Comment: Thanks for your comment.